# DB Performance - Left outer join over database funtion

Tags: database

This is a bit complex query which has multiple joins and reruns a lot of records with several data fields. Let’s say it basically use to retrieve manager details.

**First set of tables** (already implemented query):

Select  m.name, d.name, d.address, m.salary , m.age,……
From manager m,department d,…..etc
JOINS …..

**Assume, a one manger can have zero or more employees.**

Let’s say I need to list down all employee names for each and every manager for result of first set of tables with managers who has no employees (which means want to keep the manager list of first set of tables as it is).
Then I have to access “employee” table through “party” tables (might be involved few more tables).

**Second set of tables** (to be newly connected):

That means there are one or more join with “employee” , “party” and …..etc
I have two approaches on this.

1. Make left outer join with first set of tables to second set of
   tables.
2. Create a user define function (UDF) in DB level for second set of
   tables. Then I have to  insert manger id in to this UDF as a
   parameter and take all the employees (e1,e2,…) as a formatted string
   by calling through the select clause in the first set of tables

Please can someone suggest me the best solution in DB performance wise out of these two options?

Comment: Performance questions cannot be answered well generically. You really should say which RDBMS you're using, if you want the best answers.

Answer (score 0):

Go for the JOIN, using appropriate WHERE clauses and indexes.

The database engine is far better at optimizing that you'll ever be.  Let it do its job.

Your way sounds like (n+1) query death.

Write a sample query and ask your database to EXPLAIN PLAN to see what the cost is.  If you spot a TABLE